# Импортировать переменную из другого файла JS (Расширения Chrome)

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, chrome-extension

Пишу расширения для Chrome (я новичок в этом деле).
Столкнулся с проблемой: у меня есть 2 js файла(content.js и expensive_stickers.js).

Код expensive_stickers.js

```
export var sticker = "test_sticker";
```

Код content.js

```
import {sticker} from "./expensive_stickers.js"
alert(sticker);
```

Файл manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "TEST EX",
    "description": "Добавляем некоторые полезные штуки на ваш любимый сайт",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "author": "Mikhail",
    "icons": {"128": "icon.png"},
  
    "action": {
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "icon.png",
        "32": "icon.png",
        "48": "icon.png",
        "128": "icon.png"
      },
      
    "default_title": "Нажмите, чтобы настроить",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://lis-skins.ru/market/csgo/*",
                "https://lis-skins.ru/market/dota2/*",
                "https://lis-skins.ru/market/rust/*",
                "https://lis-skins.ru/market/",
                "https://lis-skins.ru/profile/*"
            ],
            "js": ["jquery.min.js", "expensive_stickers.js", "content.js"]
        }
    ],
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"]
}
```

Я хочу получать значение переменой sticker из файла expensive_stickers.js в файл content.js

Способ, что я использую выше приводит к ошибке: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'` для expensive_stickers.js и `Cannot use import statement outside a module` для content.js

Как можно добиться желаемого результата?

Comment: Если кратно - обработайте ваши файлы каким-нибудь вебпаком перед тем как складывать их в расширение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы использовать import ваши файлы должны быть обработаны как type=module. Chrome это не делает в расширении, поэтому или соберите все файлы каким либо сборщиком наподобие webpack или просто используйте window.